# Development and Testing - Organizations APIs - LinkedIn API

Tags: linkedin-api

LinkedIn provides 2 public organization API for development purpose:
[link](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/organizations/development-testing)

But when I try to access these organization using:
[link](https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationPageStatistics?q=organization&organization=6177438&oauth2_access_token=%7B%20access%20token%20%7D)

It is showing following API fail message:

> {"serviceErrorCode":100,"message":"Not enough permissions to access: GET-organization /organizationPageStatistics","status":403}

**Is there any problem with my current flow?**

Answer (score 0):

From the docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/page-statistics#parameters it looks like the organization id is formatted differently

https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationPageStatistics?q=organization&organization=urn:li:organization:6177438

**Edit**: Also, auth tokens are not spec'd to be used as query parameters. You're meant to follow these steps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authorization-code-flow?context=linkedin/marketing/context and then use the token in the request header.

Comment: Still same problem